# How to get a good stack trace in Sentry for React Native?

Tags: react-native, sentry, react-native-sentry

I log my errors in Sentry, but the stack trace that is uploaded doesn't help. It displays only trace like this:

[image] And it doesn't let me see into where in the JS the error occurred. How do I map these to a more descriptive stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload [source maps](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/sourcemaps/)